# Azure DevOps Attempt to remap source folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am been trying to download an sln from Azure DevOps but I get this message that wants me to remap the local path. The current mapped local is correct where I want it on my desktop but this pop-up comes up and then I can't open the project file.

[image]

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 3
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = https://nccn.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection
        SccProjectUniqueName0 = ..\\NCCN\u0020Libraries\\GuidelineDataLayer\\GuidelineDataLayer\\GuidelineDataLayer.csproj
        SccProjectName0 = ../../NCCN\u0020Libraries/GuidelineDataLayer/GuidelineDataLayer
        SccLocalPath0 = ..\\NCCN\u0020Libraries\\GuidelineDataLayer\\GuidelineDataLayer
        SccLocalPath1 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = NccnWebApi\\Nccn.WebService.GAT.csproj
        SccProjectName2 = NccnWebApi
        SccLocalPath2 = NccnWebApi
    EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Check what's in the SLN and csproj files. There are some `Scc` properties in the csproj - make sure they are all `SAK`. In the SLN, check for any dodginess in the `Scc` global section

Comment: @DaveShaw, I updated with the GlobalSection do I need to change the SccLocalPath0?

Comment: If the GlobalSection is messed up, I'd suggest deleting the whole GlobalSection and then "re-binding" the solution again.